# Simple Client Server Application, but something is going wrong

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

I am using Socket and ServerSocket classes to communicate on local host
client sends a no. to server and server computes square of no. and sends back to the client

```
// Client Class


import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

class SocketDemo

{

public static void main(String...arga) throws Exception
{
    Socket          s = null;
    PrintWriter    pw = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    System.out.println("Enter a number one digit");
    int i=(System.in.read()-48); // will read only one character
    System.out.println("Input number is "+i);
    try
    {
        s  = new Socket("127.0.0.1",10101);
        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Connection established, streams created");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in Client "+e);
    }
    pw.println(i);
    System.out.println("Data sent to server");
    String str = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("The square of "+i+" is "+str);
}
```

}

```
// Server Side

import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

class ServerSocketDemo

{

public static void main(String...args)
{
    ServerSocket ss=null;
    PrintWriter    pw = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    int i=0;
    try
    {
        ss = new ServerSocket(10101);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in Server while creating connection"+e);
    }
    System.out.print("Server is ready");
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println ("  Waiting for connection....");
        Socket s=null;
        try
        {
            s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection established with client");
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            i = new Integer(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("i is "+i);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception in Server "+e);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection established with "+s);
        i*=i;
        pw.println(i);
        try
        {
            pw.close();
            br.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception while closing streams");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please Help

Comment: Ok...So what is the problem?

Comment: i am not able to ger the square from the server, 
i added these debugging statements to both the classes and found that something is wrong when server reads the message
just execute both the codes by making seperate classes and you would get my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On client side do this after sending data to server

```
 pw.println(i);
 pw.flush();
```